# Масштаб и центрирование изображения в блоке

Tags: jquery, img, центрирование

Есть блок, размеры которого могут быть произвольны. Блок содержит изображение (тег img, не background.

**Задача:** размещать изображение по центру блока, при этом заполняя все пространство, и, конечно, не искажать само изображение. Проще говоря, нужен аналог background-size: cover, только для изображения, заданного в html.

*Код, который является наиболее подходящим:*

```
var box = $('.img-holder'),
    img = $('img', box),
    imgW = img.width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    img.css({
        marginLeft: (box.width() - imgW) / 2
    });
}).resize();
```

*Но, условиям он отвечает не полностью. Если изображение сильно меньше родительского блока, то получается пустота слева. При изменении высота родителя, изображение тоже не изменяется.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Чтобы изображение не искажалось - `object-fit: cover;`
2. Для заполнения всего пространства блока задаем для изображения `width: 100%; height: 100%;`

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.block-200x200 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
</div>
<div class="block block-200x200">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, почти идеальное, спасибо. Но, к сожалению не до конца кроссбраузерное. До IE11 включительно, object-fit: не поддерживается..

Comment: для кроссбраузерности - https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images

Comment: Большое спасибо, пожалуй, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**

Скрипт, который полностью решает данную задачу:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function fix_size() {
        var images = $('.midnight img');
        images.each(setsize);

        function setsize() {
            var img = $(this),
                img_dom = img.get(0),
                container = img.parents('.midnight');
            if (img_dom.complete) {
                resize();
            } else img.one('load', resize);

            function resize() {
                if ((container.width() / container.height()) > (img_dom.width / img_dom.height)) {
                    img.width('100%');
                    img.height('auto');
                } else {
                    img.height('100%');
                    img.width('auto');
                }
                var marginx=(img.width()-container.width())/-2,
                    marginy=(img.height()-container.height())/-2;
               console.log(marginx);
               img.css({'margin-left': marginx, 'margin-top': marginy});

            }
        }
    }
    $(window).on('resize', fix_size);
    fix_size();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load resize', onResize);

function onResize() {
  var $blocks = $('.block');
  
  $blocks.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $img = $this.find('.block__img');
    
    $img.css($this.width() / $img.width() >= $this.height() / $img.height()
      ? { width: '100%', height: 'auto' }
      : { width: 'auto', height: '100%' }
    );
  });
}
```

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;
}

.block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.block--square { width: 40%; }
.block--square::after { padding-bottom: 100%; }

.block--horizontal { width: 40%; }
.block--horizontal::after { padding-bottom: 75%; }

.block--vertical { width: 40%; }
.block--vertical::after { padding-bottom: 125%; }

.block__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block block--square">
  <img src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201411/05/1324489/citilegs01.jpg" alt="" class="block__img"/>
</div>
<div class="block block--horizontal">
  <img src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201411/05/1324489/citilegs01.jpg" alt="" class="block__img"/>
</div>
<div class="block block--vertical">
  <img src="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201411/05/1324489/citilegs01.jpg" alt="" class="block__img"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Несколько замудрено, многовато кода, но спасибо за вариант

Comment: @Amsterdam, самому больше нравится вариант с полифилом из-за "малого кол-ва кода", но дефакто, кода там ещё больше (если jquery уже включен в проект), не говоря уже о поддержке кода "потомками". Да и вообще честно говоря не вижу смысла и в том и в другом, через бекграунд можно сделать какой угодно респонсив блок с изображением.

Comment: вариант с css не всегда подойдет. Например, когда картинки загружаются через админку менеджером. Да и для СЕО лишняя картинка на странице, так сказать, не лишняя. Бэкграунды не индексируются.

Comment: @Amsterdam, инлайновый `style="background-image: url()"` никто не отменял, что же касается сео, то тут я не знаю, но можно и продублировать с `display: none;` Не, я не против, просто как по мне, js полифилы для имитации `css` это слишком жирно и не оправдано.